# How to test TcpListener for localhost and port number in c#

Tags: c#, localhost, tcplistener

I have a code in c# which reads the data from tcp ipaddress and port number but my problem is this that i dont have any testing plateform with ipaddress and port number to test the application.My concern is this that is there any way by which i can test my code in local environmnet..

Here is my code..

```
 public class Listener
{

    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;
    // Set the TcpListener on port 8081.
    Int32 port = 8081;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3");
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

    public void ListenForClients()
    {

        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
    public void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("socket");
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("disc");
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            String textdata = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\ipdata.txt", textdata);


        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the TCP listening application, you obviously need to write TCP transferring one. You can write it and:

- Run them simultaneously

OR

- Run listener on your OS and transmitter in virtual machine. I made so and has written a [post on my blog](http://wantcode.tk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf-tcp/) on Russian (sources are also available for download).

Comment: can i test this application on localhost

Comment: @Adi Yes, set transferring and receiving IP to the same 127.0.0.1

Comment: and what will be the port number here

Comment: @Adi Almost any above 2000, it must be free of usage by other processes

Comment: port = 8081 and ip = 127.0.0.1 i have put ..is it ok ?

Comment: @Adi You're asking like you're afraid to break something ;) Use any

Comment: Am sorry sir this is the first time i am working on TcpListener ...Thanks a lot..

Comment: After a few tests going crazy over the same thing, in the end going for no security over the internet at all (firewall totally disabled, DMZ etc...), it turns out TcpClient does not accept "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", but only the actual local IP address of the machine running the server app... Maybe some setting in the router... :/

Comment: Linked page is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure the listener to 127.0.0.1 and test logic via localhost connetcion if you have transmitting part of system

Comment: 8081, if you soft push data to that port

Answer (score 0):

Use RESTClient chrome/firefox AddOn (http://restclient.net/) to send data to IP and Port in Intranet environment, I use this